# can't access object within UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: uiview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am doing a bezier animation with programmatically generated objects. The number of objects could be bigger than 100. These objects are also responsive to touch.

The animation works fine. Now I would like to make some objects drag-able.

However, I can't access the individual objects in the UIPanGestureRecognizer function. I assume I m doing something wrong with class / subclass calling, but can't think of it..

The tutorials I looked into had IBOutlets or dedicated class variables for every animated object on screen.. I do have a potential high number of objects that are generated within the FOR loop..

What approach do you suggest?

```
func panning(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(pan.view!)
    var translation  = pan.translationInView(self.view)

    pan.view.center = CGPointMake(pan.view.center.x + translation.x, pan.view.center.y + translation.y)

    pan.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)


        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panning:");
                }
}
```

.. within viewDidLoad the function gets called:

```
    // loop from 0 to 50
    for i in 0...50 {

        // create a square object
        let square = UIView()
        square.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 40, height: 40)
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(square)


        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panning:");
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        square.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        panGesture.delegate = self;
```

Thanks to the feedback from Rob, here's an updated version:

I don't really know how to do add the AllowUserInteraction to CAKeyframeAnimation (Rob's answer 3a), as it does not have an "option" field (I m a noob).

Stopping the animation for the object being moved (Rob's answer 3b) completely eludes me. But its something definitely necessary in here.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    srand48(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

    // loop from 0 to 5
    for i in 0...5 {

        // create a square
        let square = UIView()
        square.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 40, height: 40)
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.view.addSubview(square)
        //square.userInteractionEnabled = true;


        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panning:");
        square.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)



        // randomly create a value between 0.0 and 150.0
        let randomYOffset = CGFloat( drand48() * 150)

        // for every y-value on the bezier curve
        // add our random y offset so that each individual animation
        // will appear at a different y-position
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: -16,y: 239 + randomYOffset))
        path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 375, y: 239 + randomYOffset), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 136, y: 373 + randomYOffset), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 178, y: 110 + randomYOffset))

        // create the animation
        let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        anim.path = path.CGPath
        anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        //anim.duration = 5.0

        // each square will take between 4.0 and 8.0 seconds
        // to complete one animation loop
        anim.duration = 4.0 + 3 * drand48()

        // stagger each animation by a random value
        // `290` was chosen simply by experimentation
        anim.timeOffset = 290 * drand48()


        // add the animation 
        square.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animate position along path")
    }
}


func panning(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if pan.state == .Began {
        println("pan began")
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(pan.view!)

    } else if pan.state == .Changed {

        println("pan state changed")

        var translation  = pan.translationInView(self.view)

        pan.view?.center = CGPointMake(pan.view!.center.x + translation.x, pan.view!.center.y + translation.y)

        pan.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        println("translation")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things jump out at me:

1. Your `for` loop is setting delegates for `recognizer` (which is not needed unless you're doing something particular which you haven't shared with us) and `panGesture` (which should be removed because `panGesture` is not a variable that you have set in this `for` loop and seems to be completely unrelated). Thus it would be:

   ```
   for i in 0...50 {
       let square = UIView()
       square.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 40, height: 40)
       square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
       self.view.addSubview(square)

       let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panning:");
       square.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
   }
   ```
2. In `panning` you are instantiating a new `panGesture`: You definitely want to get rid of that. A gesture handler has no business creating new gestures. So get rid of the line that starts with `let panGesture = ...`.
3. In your original question, you hadn't shared the animation you're doing. If you were animating using block-based animation, you have to specify the `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` options. Also, if you'd start dragging it around a view that is being animated, you'd also want to (a) stop the animation for that view; and (b) reset the `frame` in accordance with the `presentationLayer`.

   But, it's now clear that you're using `CAKeyframeAnimation`, in which case, there is no `AllowUserInteraction` mechanism. So, instead, you have to add the gesture recognizer to the `superview`, and then iterate through the frames of the squares (as represented by their presentation layer, i.e. the location mid-animation) and test to see if you get any hits.
4. It's up to you, but I find the pan gesture is a little slow to start recognizing the gesture (as it differentiates between a pan and a tap. In this case, you want something a little more responsive, methinks, so I might use a long press gesture recognizer with a

So, pulling that all together, you end up with something like:

```
var squares = [UIView]() // an array to keep track of all of the squares

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    srand48(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

    // loop from 0 to 5
    for i in 0...5 {

        // create a square
        let square = UIView()
        square.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 40, height: 40)
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.view.addSubview(square)

        squares.append(square)

        // randomly create a value between 0.0 and 150.0
        let randomYOffset = CGFloat( drand48() * 150)

        // for every y-value on the bezier curve
        // add our random y offset so that each individual animation
        // will appear at a different y-position
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: -16,y: 239 + randomYOffset))
        path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 375, y: 239 + randomYOffset), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 136, y: 373 + randomYOffset), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 178, y: 110 + randomYOffset))

        // create the animation
        let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        anim.path = path.CGPath
        anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        //anim.duration = 5.0

        // each square will take between 4.0 and 8.0 seconds
        // to complete one animation loop
        anim.duration = 4.0 + 3 * drand48()

        // stagger each animation by a random value
        // `290` was chosen simply by experimentation
        anim.timeOffset = 290 * drand48()

        // add the animation
        square.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animate position along path")
    }

    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:");
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

var viewToDrag: UIView!          // which of the squares are we dragging
var viewToDragCenter: CGPoint!   // what was the `center` of `viewToDrag` when we started to drag it
var originalLocation: CGPoint!   // what was gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!) when we started dragging

func handleLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!)

    if gesture.state == .Began {
        for square in squares {
            let presentationLayer = square.layer.presentationLayer() as CALayer
            let frame = presentationLayer.frame
            if CGRectContainsPoint(frame, location) {
                viewToDrag = square
                viewToDragCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))
                viewToDrag.layer.removeAnimationForKey("animate position along path")
                viewToDrag.center = viewToDragCenter
                originalLocation = location
                return
            }
        }
    } else if gesture.state == .Changed {
        if viewToDrag != nil {
            var translation = CGPointMake(location.x - originalLocation.x, location.y - originalLocation.y)
            viewToDrag.center = CGPointMake(viewToDragCenter.x + translation.x, viewToDragCenter.y + translation.y)
        }
    } else if gesture.state == .Ended {
        viewToDrag = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I basically copied your suggestions - which all were spot on into my tiny example (updated above). The implementation of 3a) and 3b) are still somewhat difficult for me, but you guess right in terms of desired functionality.

Comment: @SantaChris Yeah, that observation regarding `.AllowUserInteraction` is only applicable if you were doing block-based animation, but you were using `CAKeyframeAnimation`, so that's not applicable. I've revised my answer to show how you might grab items being animated with key frame animation and drag them around.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the perfect answer above. This completely solves my question. Your much appreciated!